# pressing enter to continue in program (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, enter, mars-simulator

So I made a simple RPG text-based adventure game in mips (it's around 2200 lines of code and not really relevant to my question so I won't post it). I want to format it so after a line of text is printed, the user must press enter to display the next line (aka continue to the next instruction), similar to how videogame text boxes work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You could steal some code from [More](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html)

Comment: MARS has syscall service to [read character `v0=12`](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html), but I'm not sure if the character is echoed back into console window, or not, and if you mind, or not. If it works for you, you can use this service to wait for user input, and then either check if it was enter (13 or 10 value? Try with debugger, put breakpoint after syscall and hit enter, to see what is the result), or not to check anything (creating "press any key" pause).

Comment: If the console window input/output interference is too big for your purpose, there's maybe some other ways to read keyboard in MARS? How would actually action game read the state of keyboard? Is it even possible with MARS? Hmm... I never looked for that, so I'm not sure, I know it has extra bitmap display which you can attach to the machine (I mean virtually in the simulator), but I'm not sure if it has also input device which can be continuously polled without syscall or pause. Definitely not in default `syscall` services, so it's maybe some another extension like bitmap display or no way.

Comment: According to this project there indeed is external keyboard device, which can be attached to MARS too (again I mean the virtual external device, like the bitmap display tool plugin): https://github.com/AndrewHamm/MIPS-Pong  .. but try first the default console read char, I think it may work well for you, unless it will require to switch focus between console and bitmap windows to register the key press, that would be unfortunate, but if console reads the input even when bitmap window is focused, you should be fine with syscall.

Comment: for now, i'm using MIP's sleep syscall to make it easier to read. i'd rather do the former, but this also works for the time being

Answer (score 0):

I added something like this in a small program I did. I used a prompt then read a char. I put this on loop until the user pressed Enter, ASCII code 10. Some posts will call the ENTER key as ASCII 13 (carriage return), but it reads as 10 on my Mac. Either way, you could also display the read char as an int (sys code 1) to see what you are getting (10 or 13).

Here are the code pieces I used:

```
.data
    contPrompt: .asciiz "Press ENTER to continue...\n"
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"



.text

# your other code goes here

    jal readEnter

# next instruction in your code
```

....

```
readEnter: # Ask user to press ENTER to continue
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, contPrompt
    syscall
    li $v0, 12 # sys code for readchar
    syscall

    move $t0, $v0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall

    bne $t0, 10, readEnter # repeat if not ENTER

    jr $ra # return to the calling subroutine
```

I am not sure if you are looking for something more sophisticated, but this works well for my purposes.